# Relative elements position in visibility toggling

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I made several simplest **jquery** widgets,  visibility of which is controlled by toggle buttons.

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default content-panel">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default control-panel" role="navigation">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
           <label id="Btn1" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">
            <input type="checkbox"/> Widget 1
          </label>
           <label id="Btn2" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">
            <input type="checkbox"/> Widget 2
          </label>
          <label id="Btn3" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">
            <input type="checkbox"/> Widget 3

            </label>  
         </div>
    </nav>

  <div id="widgetsArea" style="height: 91%;">

      <div id="widget1" class="ui-widget-content widget-style">
          <h5 class="ui-widget-header">Widget 1</h5> 
      </div>

      <div id="widget2" class="ui-widget-content widget-style">
          <h5 class="ui-widget-header">Widget 2</h5> 
      </div>

      <div id="widget3" class="ui-widget-content widget-style">
          <h5 class="ui-widget-header">Widget 3</h5> 
      </div>
   </div>   
</div
```

Javascript:

```
//set buttons in active
$("#Btn1, #Btn2, #Btn3")
.button('toggle')
.find(':checkbox')
.prop('checked');

$("#Btn1").change(function()
{
    $('#widget1').toggle();
}); 

$("#Btn2").change(function()
{
    $('#widget2').toggle();
});

$("#Btn3").change(function()
{
    $('#widget3').toggle();
});
```

But I have little problem: when the widget is hidden, other underlying widgets offsets up - http://jsfiddle.net/wq4c3/15/

I tried to resolve this problem by setting widgets position explicitly (http://jsfiddle.net/NEsw8/1/):

```
$("#Btn1").change(function()
{
    var tp2 = $('#widget2').offset().top;
    var lf2 = $('#widget2').offset().left;
    var tp3 = $('#widget3').offset().top;
    var lf3 = $('#widget3').offset().left;
    $('#widget1').toggle();
    $('#widget2').offset({ top: tp2, left: lf2 });
    $('#widget3').offset({ top: tp3, left: lf3 });
}); 

$("#Btn2").change(function()
{
    var tp1 = $('#widget1').offset().top;
    var lf1 = $('#widget1').offset().left;
    var tp3 = $('#widget3').offset().top;
    var lf3 = $('#widget3').offset().left;
    $('#widget2').toggle();
    $('#widget1').offset({ top: tp1, left: lf1 });
    $('#widget3').offset({ top: tp3, left: lf3 });
});

$("#Btn3").change(function()
{
    var tp1 = $('#widget1').offset().top;
    var lf1 = $('#widget1').offset().left;
    var tp2 = $('#widget2').offset().top;
    var lf2 = $('#widget2').offset().left;
    $('#widget3').toggle();
    $('#widget1').offset({ top: tp1, left: lf1 });
    $('#widget2').offset({ top: tp2, left: lf2 });
});
```

It works with some problems in real project (in google chrome), and I want to understand whether there are better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of absolute positioning try, visibility

```
//set buttons in active
$("#Btn1, #Btn2, #Btn3")
    .button('toggle')
    .find(':checkbox')
    .prop('checked');

function toggleVisibility(el) {
    $(el).css('visibility', function (i, visibility) {
        return visibility == 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'
    });
}


$("#Btn1").change(function () {
    toggleVisibility('#widget1')
});

$("#Btn2").change(function () {
    toggleVisibility('#widget2')
});

$("#Btn3").change(function () {
    toggleVisibility('#widget3')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XN5RB/)